# How to send a String array as basic name value pair as HTTPPOST?

Tags: java, android, json, http

I want to send a array as name value pair as httppost.My server accepts only array values.The following is my code snippet..

```
public String SearchWithType(String category_name, String[] type,int page_no) {

    String url = "http://myURL";
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    String auth_token = Login.authentication_token;
    String key = Login.key;

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authentication_token",
                auth_token));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category_name",
                category_name));
        int i = 0;
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type[i]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", String.valueOf(page_no)));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        eu = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        String ex = ioe.toString();
        return ex;
    }

    return eu;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. What did you do in php side for retrieving type[i] array? Please give a hint. normal `$type= $_GET['type'];` doesn't work.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611213/send-string-b-httprequest-and-get-in-php-b-get?noredirect=1#comment34429597_22611213

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I got the issue. Here's how:

```
try {
    int i = 0;

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authentication_token", auth_token));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category_name", category_name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", type[i]));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", String.valueOf(page_no)));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    eu = EntityUtils.toString(entity).toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
}
```

All I had to do was initialize a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type[]",type[i]));
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. What should I do in php side for retrieving type[i] array? Please give a hint. normal `$type= $_GET['type'];` doesn't work.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611213/send-string-b-httprequest-and-get-in-php-b-get?noredirect=1#comment34429597_22611213

Answer (score 0):

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", Arrays.toString(type)));
```

Comment: i tried that but it gives the string interpretation of the array...however the backend needs the array value and not to string interpretation of that array

Answer (score 0):

convert from array to string and then send using http post,again server side parse from String to array

Answer (score 0):

json_array = [{param1:"param1Value", param2:"param2Value"}]
if you want send a json array with nameValuePairs you can send like this;

```
new BasicNameValuePairs("param[0][param1]","param1Value")
new BasicNameValuePairs("param[0][param2]","param2Value")
```