# send String[] b httprequest and get in php b $_GET

Tags: java, php, json, httprequest

I want to send a `String[]` by an HTTP request and get the values in PHP with the `$_GET` method.
The total number of values in the `String[]` is variable.
I have tried so far:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
String[] dropdowns = {"1st item","2nd item","3rd item","4th item"};
for (int i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", dropdowns[i]));
}
```

In PHP I want to get all values and query based on them.

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
```

And use them like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Apps WHERE pid[0] = $pid" AND pid[1] = $pid" 
AND ...);
```

But I know this way is wrong.
How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe if you use the name 'pid[]' in params.add. But what you see in PHP page when send httprequest? Try put a var_dump($_GET) to see.

Comment: how can I use  var_dump($_GET) in php to retrieve pid[i] numbers?

Comment: in place of $pid = $_GET['pid']. Put var_dump($_GET);. So PHP dump var $_GET than cotains the parameter send with Java. But you have to made a httprequest from Java to PHP page to see what is send.

Comment: Alright. How haw I retrieve pid[i] for n numbers of items in php then?

Comment: PHP receiving 'pid' parameter like array? The var_dump is to see this.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an array through HTTP request UNLESS you have an array of inputs such as:

```
<input type='text' name='manyOfThese[]' />
```

To send an array you have two options. One is to use serialize() and unserialize() to turn your array into a string. And the other is to use session variables:

```
$_SESSION['pid'] = $pid;
```

Then on the next script

```
$pid = $_SESSION['pid'];
unset($_SESSION['pid']);
 foreach($pid as $element){
    echo $element //or do whatever you need to do to that variable
}
```

Also at the beginning of your scripts you will want to include:
    session_start();

And then when your php application is exited (upon logoff for example):
    session_destroy();

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can I retrieve pid[i] for n numbers of items in p'p?

Comment: see addition with foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM Apps WHERE pid[0] = $pid" AND pid[1] = $pid" AND ...);
```

Is very wrong and unsafe. (Columns wrong syntax, SQL injection, wrong quotation, wrong SQL syntax,...)

Must be something like

```
$result = mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM Apps WHERE pid
            IN(" . implode(',', mysql_real_escape_string($pid)) . ")
          ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a serialized reprezentation of the values you want to send in the url. It has limitations such as the max length of the url.

```
'http://domain.com/data_handler.php?data=' . urlencode(serialize($array1));
```

Getting back your array:

```
$array1 = unserialize($_GET['data']);
```

Its even better to create a post request and use this syntax:

```
pid[]=1 
pid[]=2
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this and both involve loops. First, when you are sending the data, put the brackets in the name to send it as an array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid[]", dropdowns[i]));
}
```

Second, on the php end this array is stored in `$_GET['pid']` or `$_POST['pid']` depending on how you sent it, so you would loop through the array and add the items to your sql query. Just make a separate variable to store the sql statement so you can add to it:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($_GET['pid'] as $value) {
    $yourSQLString .= " AND pid[". $x ."] = '" . $value . "'";
    $x++;
}
```

And obviously you should do something else with the actual value to avoid sql injections.