# HTTPPOST with JSON Object having array

Tags: arrays, json, parameters, http-post, namevaluecollection

below is my json object i need to pass on my server:

```
{
    "PostImages": [{
        "FileFormat": "jpeg",
        "id": "0",
        "FileByteArray": "LONG BYTE ARRAY OF FILE",
        "FileCaption": "",
        "VideoLink": ""
    },{
        "FileFormat": "jpeg",
        "id": "0",
        "FileByteArray": "LONG BYTE ARRAY OF FILE",
        "FileCaption": "",
        "VideoLink": ""
    }],
    "AdminScheduleId": "0",
    "CategoryId": "1",
    "UserId": "4",
    "Presenter2": "0",
    "IdeaTitle": "gfgfdgdfgdfg",
    "IsImplementedByOwn": "false",
    "NoOfVolunteer": "0",
    "PostId": "0",
    "ClubId": "2",
    "Description": " Dfgdfgdf",
    "Presenter1": "0"
}
```

I have already done it with passing json object to server. But it create issue just because of the long byte array.

See my Below working code:

```
String res = null;

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(CREATE_IDEA_URL);
    request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    //request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    try {

        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(PostImages); // Array of Images details

        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject()
                    .put("IdeaTitle",IdeaTitle)
                    .put("Description",Description)
                    .put("IsImplementedByOwn",IsImplementedByOwn)
                    .put("NoOfVolunteer",NoOfVolunteer)
                    .put("PostId",PostId)
                    .put("UserId",UserId)
                    .put("ClubId",ClubId)
                    .put("AdminScheduleId",AdminScheduleId)
                    .put("CategoryId",categoryId)
                   .put("Presenter1",Presenter1)
                   .put("Presenter2",Presenter2)
                    .put("PostImages",array);
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jObject.toString(2),  "UTF-8"); // ADD THIS LINE TO HAVE ARABIC LANGUAGE IN POST
        System.out.println("jObject is:::: "+jObject.toString());
        request.setEntity(entity);
        System.out.println("====the Entity is: "+entity.toString());    

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //----------------------
        if(LC5_API.getCookiesFromLC5() == null){
        }else{
         CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
            for(Cookie cook : LC5_API.getCookiesFromLC5()){
                cookieStore.addCookie(cook); 
            }
            ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        }   

        //-------------------
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        //res = response.toString();
        int resCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Our Res: "+jObject.toString());
        System.out.println("Result code: "+resCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line="";
        StringBuffer returnFromServer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line=in.readLine())!=null){
            returnFromServer.append(line);
        }
        //Toast what we got from server
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),returnFromServer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        System.out.println("Responce: "+returnFromServer.toString());
        res = returnFromServer.toString();

        if (entity != null){
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        res=null;
    }

    System.out.println("Responcre is:"+res);
    return res;*/

}
public static String Get_AdoptIdea(String PostId) {
    String responce = null;
    RestClient client = new RestClient(GET_ADOPT_IDEA);

//  if(LC5_API.DEBUG) Log.d("SetCookie", LC5_API.SESSION_COOKIEName + ":"+ LC5_API.SESSION_COOKIEValue+"");
//  client.AddHeader("Cookie", SESSION_COOKIEName+"="+LC5_API.SESSION_COOKIEValue);

    client.AddParam("postId", PostId);

    try {
        client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        responce = client.getResponse();
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "");
        responce=null;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        responce=null;
    }

    if(DEBUG)Log.d(TAG, "Response: "+responce);
    return responce;
```

Above code works perfect. But i want to send it with namevaluepair to the server.

See my below code:

```
String res = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
        String URL = CREATE_IDEA_URL;
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

        List<NameValuePair> postParameters;
        postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PostId", PostId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IdeaTitle",IdeaTitle));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Description",Description));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IsImplementedByOwn",IsImplementedByOwn));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NoOfVolunteer",NoOfVolunteer));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PostId",PostId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserId",UserId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ClubId",ClubId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AdminScheduleId",AdminScheduleId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CategoryId",categoryId));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Presenter1",Presenter1));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Presenter2",Presenter2));


        //postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PostImages",ctx.getString(R.string.json_object_test)));

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(PostImages);

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



        for(int i=0; i<array.length();i++){
            ImagesData img = new ImagesData();


            String video = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("VideoLink").equalsIgnoreCase("") ? "xyz" : array.getJSONObject(i).getString("VideoLink");
            System.out.println("VIDEO:: "+video);

            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileCaption", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("FileCaption")));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileFormat", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("FileFormat")));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VideoLink", video));
            param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FileByteArray", array.getJSONObject(i).getString("FileByteArray")));

            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PostImages",param.toString()));  
        }

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

        post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        if(LC5_API.DEBUG) Log.d("REQUEST FROM REST:", "The requested String is:"+CREATE_IDEA_URL+postParameters);

        //--------------------------------

        if(LC5_API.getCookiesFromLC5() == null){

        }else{
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
            //-------------------------------------------
            for(Cookie cook : LC5_API.getCookiesFromLC5()){
                cookieStore.addCookie(cook); 
            }
            ((AbstractHttpClient) client).setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        }

        //---------------------------------
        HttpResponse responsePost = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntityPost = responsePost.getEntity();  
        if (resEntityPost != null) 
        {
            String response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntityPost);
            res = response;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return res;
```

Now, when i passes values with above code it gives me Invalid JSON Primitive: IdeaTitle.

Everything is fine but not getting proper response. Please help me for how to pass json object having json array.

FYI, postImages is my json array with some details.

Please help me.

Comment: try this solution-hope it helps -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/21154349/1225413

Comment: @AkhilJain I have already try it. Please see my code. But its not working...

Comment: postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PostImages[]","try to put individual object here"));

Comment: OK but my field parameter name is "PostImages" so will it be worked? and PostImages is arraylist

Comment: iterate over arraylist and put in same key, it should work as per given answer

Comment: @AkhilJain, can you please put answer with the section of code for how to post that whole object in NameValuePair, So i can check it and if it workes i will accept your answer. Thanks for helping.