# Getting "[ ]" as response from php server which is supposed to return a JSON array

Tags: php, android, json, http, android-asynctask

The problem I am facing is , I want to return a JSON array to android application from the server which is running PHP and MySQL. I don't get any error but code doesn't give outputs as desired. I am getting the following output after executing my code.

**Logcat entries:**

```
09-26 15:53:54.166: I/System.out(32008): Connected
09-26 15:53:54.226: D/MyActivity(32008): registered
09-26 15:53:54.266: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 254K, 2% free 16955K/17240K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
09-26 15:53:54.266: I/System.out(32008): Process Result started
09-26 15:53:54.496: I/System.out(32008): 200
09-26 15:53:54.496: I/System.out(32008): BR REader:java.io.BufferedReader@426d40e0
09-26 15:53:54.536: I/System.out(32008): String builder:[]  
09-26 15:53:54.536: I/System.out(32008): Result:[]  
09-26 15:53:54.536: I/System.out(32008): Process Result ended
09-26 15:53:54.566: D/dalvikvm(32008): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 253K, 2% free 17216K/17500K, paused 13ms, total 14ms
09-26 15:53:54.586: I/Adreno-EGL(32008): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
09-26 15:53:54.616: D/OpenGLRenderer(32008): Enabling debug mode 0
```

**And the source code is :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....................
    ....................
    syncDatabases = new SyncDatabases();

    try {
        syncDatabases.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class SyncDatabases extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String result=null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... String) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Process Result started");
            String result1=getJSONUrl(uploadDetailServerUri);
            System.out.println("Result:"+result1);

            JSONArray json=new JSONArray(result1);
            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonOb=json.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("JSON Colection:"+jsonOb.toString());
            String imageName = jsonOb.getString("imagename");
            String status = jsonOb.getString("status");
            System.out.println("ImageName:"+imageName+"Status:"+status);
            }
            System.out.println("Process Result ended");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

    public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        List<NameValuePair> nameVP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameVP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", phoneNumber));
            try {   
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameVP));
            //  httpGet.setParams(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", phoneNumber));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            System.out.println(statusCode);
            if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content,"UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("BR REader:"+reader.toString());
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(line);
            }
            } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download file..");
            }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             }
            System.out.println("String builder:"+str.toString());
             return str.toString();
     }


    }
```

**And the PHP code is :**

```
<?php
include ('mysqlconnection.php');
$mobile =  $_POST['mobile_number'];
$output = array();
$query="select name,status from content;";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output[]= array( 'imagename' => $row['name'], 'status' => $row['status'] );
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

When the httprequest was sent from browser we got the desired output (JSON array) in the browser.

I don't know why im getting only "[]" as output in logcat instead of printing the JSONArray values. Help me out and thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131015/how-to-send-a-string-array-as-basic-name-value-pair-as-httppost

Comment: Make sure your query returns any result.

Comment: Well have you tested the php? because `[]` is json for an empty array, probably your sql is not returning any results

Comment: seems no records returned from query. Try the sql query directly on DB and see whether it return any records.

Comment: When the httprequest was sent from browser we got the desired output (JSON array) in the browser. The query returned the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you are using reserve word, change your query

```
$query="select name,status from content;";
```

to

```
$query="select `name`,`status` from content";
```

Comment: The query returns values correctly. And if I give within quotes(as you mentioned) I get only 'name' and 'status' as my json value when tried from browser.