# Android: How to send strings of array in a HttpPost method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

I am trying to send an array of strings to the server in a HttpPost method using AsyncTask. I tried several ways to do it but nothing works.

1. Sending Post body in a `StringEntity`:
   I tried to send the post body in a `StringEntitiy` like:

   ```
   String[] strings = new String[] {"201011", "201012", "201013"};
   reqJSON.put("params", strings);
   httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(reqJSON.toString(), "UTF8"));
   httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
   ```

   This goes as a string to the server: `"params":"[201011, 201012, 201013]"` to which server consider it as a string.
2. I also tried to add string of array in a `NameValuePair` as suggested in other posts by using:

   ```
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   for (String value: strings) {
       nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("params[]", value));
   }
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   ```

   But this does not work either.

It would be really helpful if I get to know how to send an array of strings in a post request to the server. Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: Tried this answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21154349/3866010

Comment: @th3pat3l: Yes I tried that answer as well but it did not work. Thanks

Comment: List<String> add values to it and send this will be sent as an array like you expected

Comment: Thank you for the comment @HourGlass, this is what  had done initially but it did not work so I am converting list of strings to String of an array and then sending it to server.

Comment: Are you getting any error? if so, please post